# Magento 2: Cron not working

Tags: magento2, crontab, magento-cron

I have created cron in **magento 2** but it run by command not run automatically run at **every 5 minutes.**

**file:** `crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="test">
        <job name="test" instance="Test\Ship\Cron\Observer" method="cronOderSync">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Cron set on system

```
*/5 * * * * php /home/var/www/html/magento/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "R$
*/5 * * * * php /home/var/www/html/magento/update/cron.php >> var/www/html/m$
*/5 * * * * php /home/var/www/html/magento/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> var$
```

If I execute command on terminal then cron is working

```
 sudo php bin/magento cron:run --group="test"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by adding some code in system cron file
 insteed of php I need to add /usr/bin/php which I get by

```
which php
```

command

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /var/www/html/magento-td/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> var/www/html/magento-td/var/log/magento.cron.log
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /var/www/html/magento-td/update/cron.php >> var/www/html/magento-td/var/log/update.cron.log
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento-td/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> var/www/html/magento-td/var/log/setup.cron.log
```